# Unable to save m2m relation modelform

Tags: django, m2m

I'm struck on saving m2m relation.

models.py

```
class BasicTag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Tag Name")
    image_class = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class ExtendedTag(models.Model):
    parent = models.ManyToManyField(BasicTag, blank=True,
                                    related_name="parent")
    category = models.ManyToManyField(BasicTag, blank=True,
                                      related_name="category")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self._id


class CombineTag(BasicTag, ExtendedTag):
    """

    """
```

forms.py

```
class CombineTagForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CombineTag
```

Now when I initialize form as

```
>form = CombineTagForm({"name":"shyam"})#this don't have any parent i.e. root tag
>form.is_valid()
True
>instance = form.save(commit = False)
>instance.save()
>form.save() #return errors
#error
ProgrammingError: column tag_extendedtag_parent.basictag_id does not exist
LINE 1: DELETE FROM "tag_extendedtag_parent" WHERE "tag_extendedtag_...
>form.save_m2m() #return errors ... struck here
```

So How should I need to save m2m field modelform. I had follow [official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) which say that

> If your model has a many-to-many relation and you specify commit=False when you save a form, Django cannot immediately save the form data for the many-to-many relation. This is because it isn’t possible to save many-to-many data for an instance until the instance exists in the database.

But I couldn't able to figure out what I am missing here.

Comment: "returns errors" is not the best of explanations. What is the exact error you get?

Comment: Why are you saving the form and then saving it again with commit=False?

Comment: It is not finding a column it is expecting. Did you add/modify the column _after_ you ran a syncdb ? If so you would have to run migrations.

Comment: @karthikr I had not made any change after syncdb

Comment: Ok. then can you check the database tables, and see if it is indeed consistent? The issue might be to do with the through table.

Comment: Here is what i think the issue is: `if request.method == 'POST'` would ensure your code runs only when the request type is `POST`. Second thing, I believe it is `instance.save_m2m()` and not `form.save_m2m()`